# BFS path in reactjs render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do i implement bfs for the given tree with the following data
and display its structure

```
Parent:
   - Child1
        - Child11
   - Child2
```

```
data: 
[{
  "id":23,"parentid":0,"children":
   [{
    "id":20,"parentid":23,"children":
      [{
       "id":62,"parentid":20,"children": 
         [{
           "id":92,"parentid":62,"children": []
         }]
     }]
   },
   {
    "id":31,"parentid":23,"children": []
   }]
}]
```

I am not able to use any reserved keyword in the render function to implement bfs algorithm.

My code :

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        newData : data,
       }
    }

  render() {

    const Emp = ({items}) => (
      <div>
      {items.map((item,i) => {
        return <div>{item.id}</div> 
      })}
      </div> 
     )

    return <div>
            <Emp items={this.state.newData} />
          </div>
  }
}

export default App;
```

I getting 23 (root) as output
how to recursively print each of its child in bfs manner?

i am not able to initialize while loops or any var in `Emp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to go through it.

You can make a component (like Emp) that will recursively render himself if there are any children (see an example: https://codepen.io/mikedane94/pen/aXLpMv).

Or you can go more **fun way**: make **deep flatten** of your array with marking elements like 'depth'.

```
[
  {
    "id": 23,
    "parentid": 0,
    "depth": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 20,
    "parentid": 23,
    "depth": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 62,
    "parentid": 20,
    "depth": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 92,
    "parentid": 62,
    "depth": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 31,
    "parentid": 23,
    "depth": 1
  }
]
```

Then just display it with flat `.map()`.

Take **complete function** that makes the stuff:

```
function flatter(data) {
  let depth = 0;
  let result = data;
  // make this instead if you don't want to mutate the data
  // let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  let goDeeper = false;
  do {
    goDeeper = false;
    result = result.reduce(
      (acc, { children, ...el }) => {
        if (Array.isArray(children) && children.length > 0) {
          goDeeper = true;
          return acc.concat({ ...el, depth }, children);
        }
        if (el.hasOwnProperty('depth')) return acc.concat({ ...el });
        return acc.concat({ ...el, depth });
      },
      []
    );
    depth += 1;
  } while(goDeeper);
  return result;
}
```